# How to count specific column name in all tables of one SQL Server Database object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count tables that have a specific column name. For instance, `dbo.Management` has 300 tables. Some tables have `ProtectionKey` column, and others don't.

I need a list of all the tables that have that column `ProtectionKey`, or at least a count of them.
I have looked into similar examples but those are either counting ALL columns in a DB or ALL columns in one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use the `sys` objects for this, as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` can return incorrect information:

```
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = N'ProtectionKey';
```

Comment: I am not so advanced, what fields should be replaced to match the name of my DB?

Comment: None, @HomeMade , you run the query with a connection to your database.

Comment: Hmm, I add `` use Management`` before that query and I get zero.

Comment: Then there are no columns in the database `Management` with the name `ProtectionKey`, @HomeMade . Simple as that.

Comment: Or the account running the script doesn't have permissions to see them

Comment: Haha, yea, but I see them, I did copied once again and here they are, not sure where the mistake was, but thank you so much.

Comment: Good point, @MartinSmith . I *assumed* the OP was running on a "privileged" account. ;)

Comment: Yes, something you would have to remind a beginner like me :).

Answer (score 2):

Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`:

```
select c.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where column_name = 'ProtectionKey';
```

This has many columns.  The ones you want are `TABLE_NAME` and `TABLE_SCHEMA`.

Also, this only works in one database at a time, so you need to run it in each database where you want to search for the tables.

Comment: `TABLE_SCHEMA` can be wrong, From the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"\*\* **Important** \*\* Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to query the sys.objects catalog view."*

Comment: I get an empty table with zero records. 
SELECT COUNT(c.COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE column_name = 'ProtectionKey';

Comment: @Larnu - If you do `EXEC sp_helptext 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'` you see that `TABLE_SCHEMA` is derived from applying `SCHEMA_NAME` to `schema_id` from `sys.objects` anyway so not sure if that warning is out dated

Comment: Interesting, @MartinSmith . Might be a question for the feedback section of that article. That note is mentioned on all the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` pages (See [`TABLES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), for example).

Comment: @HomeMade . . . (1) You need to run this in the database that has the tables.  (2) Perhaps you need something like `lower(c.Column_Name) like '%protectionkey%'`.

Comment: I've asked [the question](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/4188), in case you're interested in the answer, @MartinSmith . Seems that [in September 2019](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2984) it was still a "problem", but they gave no information as to why. The fact that is uses `sys.objects` underneath, and `SCHEMA_NAME()` in the `VIEW` suggests to me that the problem is therefore `SCHEMA_NAME()`; but that's the first I've heard.

Comment: @Larnu thanks. There is no similar warning in the docs for `SCHEMA_NAME()` so if that is the issue it should be mentioned there too

Comment: Agreed, @MartinSmith , and why I mentioned it in the GitHub report. Hopefully this one won't get glossed over as a "it's still bad, close please" *no response on why.*